# Google Sheet - IMPORTDATA - Query filters on Columns starts with

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, importdata

I am trying to get data using the IMPORTDATA function in GS and filter only columns starting with 'TEXT'.

`=IMPORTDATA("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC",",")`

From here, I am getting a lot of columns

Then I just want to filter columns starting with 'a string'.
When I use the formula below, I got en error;:

`=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=MEER%22,%22,%22),%22where Col starts with 'rates'")`

Error: NO COLUMN Col

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, importdata("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC", ","), 
  filter(data, regexmatch(chooserows(data, 1), "(?i)^rates")) 
)
```

In the event the data only ever has just one row, you can leave out `chooserows()`:

```
=let( 
  data, importdata("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC", ","), 
  filter(data, regexmatch(data, "(?i)^rates")) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197)
and
[regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).